# Remove for loops when plotting matplotlib subplots

Tags: python, performance, loops, matplotlib, plot

I have large subplot-based figure to produce in python using matplotlib. In total the figure has in excess of 500 individual plots each with 1000s of datapoints. This can be plotted using a `for` loop-based approach modelled on the minimum example given below

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

# define main plot names and subplot names
mains = ['A','B','C','D']
subs = list(range(9))

# generate mimic data in pd dataframe
col = [letter+str(number) for letter in mains for number in subs]
col.insert(0,'Time')

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=col)

for title in df.columns:
    df[title] = [i for i in range(100)]

# although alphabet and mains are the same in this minimal example this may not always be true
alphabet = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
column_names = [column for column in df.columns if column != 'Time']

# define figure size and main gridshape
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 15))
outer = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 2, wspace=0.2, hspace=0.2)

for i, letter in enumerate(alphabet):
    # define inner grid size and shape
    inner = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(3, 3,
                    subplot_spec=outer[i], wspace=0.1, hspace=0.1)

    # select only columns with correct letter
    plot_array = [col for col in column_names if col.startswith(letter)]      
        
    # set title for each letter plot
    ax = plt.Subplot(fig, outer[i])
    ax.set_title(f'Letter {letter}')
    ax.axis('off')
    fig.add_subplot(ax)
    
    # create each subplot
    for j, col in enumerate(plot_array):
        ax = plt.Subplot(fig, inner[j])   
        
        X = df['Time']
        Y = df[col]
    
        # plot waveform
        ax.plot(X, Y)

        # hide all axis ticks
        ax.axis('off')
        
        # set y_axis limits so all plots share same y_axis  
        ax.set_ylim(df[column_names].min().min(),df[column_names].max().max())
        
        fig.add_subplot(ax)
```

However this is slow, requiring minutes to plot the figure. Is there a more efficient (potentially `for` loop free) method to achieve the same result

Comment: Your problem does seem very hard to speed up. You mention getting rid of for loops, but is the overhead in them really, or in the several plot commands? I *think* it's just the inordinate amount of data you're plotting. For example, try plotting everything on the same ax and see if it takes the same time. The only solution to speed this up specifically is to do some parallel plotting with multiprocessing, although I've never done that myself. Maybe start with this: https://towardsdatascience.com/plotting-in-parallel-with-matplotlib-and-python-f7efb3d944de

Comment: Plotting all of the data on a single set of axes is considerably quicker (seconds not minutes) suggesting it is something to do with either gridspec or the loop structure. Interestingly plotting a single 'main' subplot eg. 'Letter A' takes significantly less time that 1/4 of the total time for the full figure

Comment: use multiprocessing and concatenate resulting images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with the loop is not the plotting but the setting of the axis limits with `df[column_names].min().min()` and `df[column_names].max().max()`.

Testing with 6 main plots, 64 subplots and 375,000 data points, the plotting section of the example takes approx 360s to complete when axis limits are set by searching `df` for min and max values each loop. However by moving the search for min and max outside the loops. eg

```
# set y_lims
y_upper = df[column_names].max().max()
y_lower = df[column_names].min().min()
```

and changing

```
ax.set_ylim(df[column_names].min().min(),df[column_names].max().max())
```

to

```
ax.set_ylim(y_lower,y_upper)
```

the plotting time is reduced to approx 24 seconds.